# Entity Framework 4.0 in Visual Studio 2010 Pro

Tags: visual-studio-2010, entity-framework-4

Greetings, 
I would like to use EF4 but I only have Visual studio 2010 Pro. As far as I can see, all projects types and items related to EF4 are available in Ultimate version. Is there any way I can use EF4 in Visual Studio 2010 Pro?

Comment: Entity framework tools are available in all version of Visual studio including express editions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using the Entity framework with MVC2 in VS 2010 Pro right now.[image]

Comment: Agree with Kenned. Just add a new element to your project. In the data category ... ADO.Net Entity Data Model. I'm using it with VS2010 Pro right now.

Comment: Right click anywhere in your project (more or less) Press Add -> new Item -> Visual C# -> Data

Comment: Thanks! I think I have to take a cup of very large coffee!